# Integrating SAP HANA to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, integration, google-cloud-dataflow, hana

I want to load all my data from **SAP HANA to BigQuery**.

How can we do that using **GCP Dataflow** in python or is there any python scripts available for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is the existing solution ["Export data from SAP systems to Google BigQuery through SAP Data Services"](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/sap/docs/bigquery-sap-export-using-sds) helpful at all?

Are there any specific requirements for it to be in Python?
There is also a [JDBC to BigQuery Google-provided template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#jdbctobigquery) that can help you on that (assuming you can fetch SAP HANA data using JDBC, which [seems possible](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-jdbc.html)), and the [Template code is open-source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/googlecloud-to-googlecloud/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java) (however, templates are provided in Java only).

Comment: Hi @Bruno, yes the requirement is in python . going through other links you have shared.